# HTML5 aside element is not wrapped inside the wrapper

Tags: css, html, video, alignment

I can't figure out why the body wrap element is not working properly.

I do NOT want to add additional div's and keep it in that formula.

Any ideas ?

the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>

body {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
}

aside {
    float: right;
    width: 344px;
}


aside section:first-child {
    border-color: #cc0000;
    border-style: dotted;
    border-width: 2px;
    text-align: center;
}

aside section:first-child video {
    width: 320px;
    height: 240px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

    <aside>

        <section>

            <video width=320 height=240 controls preload=none poster="https://puaction.com/vid/mainvideo/pua-video.jpg">
                <source src="https://puaction.com/vid/mainvideo/mainvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="https://puaction.com/vid/mainvideo/mainvideo.webm" type="video/webm">
                <source src="https://puaction.com/vid/mainvideo/mainvideo.ogv" type="video/ogg">
            </video>

        </section>

    </aside>

</body>
</html>
```

The jsFiddle :)

What is wrong here ?

http://jsfiddle.net/R3kBx/

Comment: The float on the aside is causing that.

Comment: Yes! I have remove the float and IT IS working. But not floating to the left :) Any idea(s) ?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working properly"? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: the same floating effect (float: right;) when float is removed it IS working but not floating to the right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `class="clearfix"` to your body. Then in your css add:

```
.clearfix:after {
   content: " "; /* Older browser do not support empty content */
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   height: 0;
   clear: both;
}
```

Comment: body:after {
   content: " ";
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   height: 0;
   clear: both;
}

Comment: Of course, that'll work too. However the clearfix class is one you'll encounter again I'm sure.